# Printing a dataframe to a pdf file

Tags: r, plot, dataframe, gridextra

I would like to print a dataframe to a pdf file. I have tried the following:

```
 pdf("myfile.pdf")
 grid.table(df)
 dev.off()
```

This actually works, but draws the dataframe with some cell fill colors, and other some formatting, as well as row numbers.

I just want to draw a dataframe with no specific formatting, and especially with no row numbers.

I also need to mention that I want to draw this dataframe along with a plot. (plot above the dataframe). I have tried using:

```
 layout(matrix(c(1,2), nrow=2, byrow=TRUE), heights = c(2,1))
```

but the dataframe shows up on top of my plot (please see below)... I am not sure why?

[image]

Is there an easy way of doing that?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not try using knitr rather than the pdf device?

Comment: The show.rownames=F argument of grid.table removes the row numbers. It seems like the output of grid.table can be tweeked a bit. ?grid.table

Comment: I am not quite familiar with `knitr`, but I would need to later have the file embedded in a Web page. I am familiar with doing so for a `png` of `pdf` file, but I am not sure what to do with `knitr`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify where you want your data frame with viewport :

```
plot(NA, xlim=c(0,2), ylim=c(0,3), bty='n', xaxt='n', yaxt='n', xlab='', ylab='')
print(grid.table(df,show.rownames=F,vp=viewport(x=0.5,y=0.1)))
```

x and y values are relatives, x=.5,y=.1 place your data.frame in the bottom middle of your plot.

Comment: Thanks. Should I get rid of `layout()` for this to work? For now, it is not changing anything :s

Comment: Yes, `layout` only goes into effect when `plot.new` is called - `grid.table` just prints on top of existing plots.

Comment: Ok, thank you. But for some odd reason, when I call `plot` to draw my graph, then `print()` for the grid.table, the plot takes up the whole pdf page, and the dataframe still shows up on top of the graph.. I am doing something wrong...

Comment: I think `vp` should be inside the bracket for `grid.table`, not inside `print()`

Comment: please don't print(), think of the (g)Trees